# how to aviod empty dynamic li in the react js

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to avoid dynamic 'li' in the list display names, I am using map function fro getting a list of names. this is the example of code I wrote to get the answer. Can anyone help on that

```
import React from "react";


    function App() {
      const people = [
        { name: 'chris' },
        { name: 'chris' },
        { name: 'chris' },
        { name: '' },
        { name: '' },
        { name: 'chris' },
        { name: 'chris' },
        { name: 'nick' }
      ];

      return (
        <div>
          {people.map(person => (
            <li>{person.name}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by avoiding dynamic 'li' ?

Comment: Please use destructing, it makes your code more readable based on AirBnB ESLint configuration. and for avoiding render see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377578/6877799).

Comment: Perhaps first filter the list and remove items where `name=''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put condition ...[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-banach-zi4kd)

```
export default function App() {
    const people = [
      { name: 'chris' },
      { name: 'chris' },
      { name: 'chris' },
      { name: '' },
      { name: '' },
      { name: 'chris' },
      { name: 'chris' },
      { name: 'nick' }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        {people.map((person,i) => (
          person.name&&<li key={i}>{person.name}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I offer you to do not use `index` as the `key` prop, it causes low performance for ReactJS comparisons, I leave upvote for your nice try. but for more information see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377578/6877799).

Comment: Thanks very much... i will not use index anymore

Answer (score 0):

Act like below:

```
import React from "react";


function App() {
  const people = [
    { name: 'chris' },
    { name: 'chris' },
    { name: 'chris' },
    { name: '' },
    { name: '' },
    { name: 'chris' },
    { name: 'chris' },
    { name: 'nick' }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
     {people.map(({ name }, index)=> name && (
       <li key={name + index}>{name}</li>
     ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Using `key` prop is necessary on the `map` function but I offer you to create `key` on your data or ask Backend developers to prepare it, like below:

```
import React from "react";


function App() {
  const people = [
    { name: 'chris', key: '345654' },
    { name: 'chris', key: '923789' },
    { name: 'chris', key: '952374' },
    { name: '', key: '100345' },
    { name: '', key: '0876367' },
    { name: 'chris', key: '123876' },
    { name: 'chris', key: '236543' },
    { name: 'nick', key: '956799' }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
     {people.map(({ name, key }, index)=> name && (
       <li key={key}>{name}</li>
     ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `key` should be unique and stable for that item is rendering.